# Force IE to prompt install Adobe SVG Viewer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, svg

I'm already using SVG, but i'm surprised that IE8 doesn't automatically prompt the user to install Adobe SVG Viewer the same way it prompts to install ActiveX.

Is there a specific way or some code in the header i would need for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified exactly what you're doing with the SVG. I assume you're including them as images in your site.

You obviously know that IE<=8 doesn't support SVG, hence why you want to use the Adobe SVG viewer.

I don't know much about this SVG viewer, but I would offer an alternative solution.

IE may not support SVG but it does support an alternative format called VML. The two formats are similar enough that a number of SVG->VML conversion tools exist, which allow you to effectively load SVG images into IE. The script converts them, and the browser displays them as VML.

The most well known one is this one: http://code.google.com/p/svg2vml/ but several others exist as well.

(I'd also like to give a mention to [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/); it probably isn't what you're looking for in this case, but is an excellent cross-browser graphics library that allows you to write scripts that draw graphics in SVG in most browsers and VML in IE)